# Easy (?) application of Lagrange multiplier

Tags: calculus, optimization, economics

I am reading a book about utility theory and there is a exercise (without solution). I can't stop thinking about this, since the normal Lagrange multiplier approach seems not to work.

We want to maximize $U(x,y,z)=xy+az$ where $a>0$ under the restriction of $x+y+z=100$.

When applying the Lagrange method we get the Lagrange function
$$\Lambda(x,y,z,\lambda)=xy+az+\lambda(100-x-y-z)$$
When we take the partial derivatives we get
$$\frac{d\Lambda}{d\lambda}=100-x-y-z$$
$$\frac{d\Lambda}{dx}=y-\lambda$$$$\frac{d\Lambda}{dy}=x-\lambda$$$$\frac{d\Lambda}{dz}=a-\lambda$$
So we can derive that $y=x=a$ and $z=100-2a$ in the optimum. Besides domain issues one can find easy counterexamples like a=10.
For $y=x=10$ and $z=80$  we get $$U(10,10,80)=900<2500=U(50,50,0)$$
Why does the Lagrange method fail here? (Or have I failed using the method?)

Comment: You only carried out part of the optimization problem. This is a Kuhn-Tucker problem over the budget set $\{ x + y + z = 100, \; x, y,z \geq 0 \}$. The boundaries need to be checked.

Comment: The lagrange multiplier method didn´t fail. $$U^*_a(x^*,y^*,z^*)=100a-a^2$$ For every value of a, you get a specific optimal value for the utility function.

Comment: @calculus This is exactly the solution I derived above and which does not hold true for every a. Let a=10, then your optimum would be 900, where I can get 2500...

Comment: @DavMat The solution above is the optimum for a given a. If you want also optimize over variable a (a is then not a parameter anymore), then you have to derive $\Lambda$ w.r.t a. $ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial a}=z=0  $. You know, that $z=100-2a$, thus $0=100-2a\Rightarrow a^*=50\Rightarrow U^*(a^*,x^*,y^*,z^*)=100\cdot 50-2500=2500$

Comment: I suggest you read the question and what OP pointed out before sprouting nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for comment. Here the utility function is Cobb-Douglas in $x$ and $y$. The optimization agent would consume equal amounts of $x$ and $y$. Given his budget set, the highest marginal utilities of $x$ and $y$, he can achieve is $50$. The marginal utility of $z$ on the other hand is the constant $a$. The agent is trading 
off the marginal utility he gets from $z$ and the two complimentary goods $x$ and $y$.

So the optimal bundle should depend on the value of $a$. There exist threshold $a_L$ such that

1. If $a < a_L$, i.e. when $a$ is sufficiently low, then no $z$ is consumed. Optimal bundle is $(50, 50, 0)$. For this to happen,

$$
100 a \leq 2500 \Rightarrow a_L = 25.
$$

2. If $a_L \leq a$, then optimal bundle is $(0,0,100)$.

The interior/Lagrange multiplier solution is never optimal since $100a \geq 100a - a^2$.

Comment: Should the second $a_L$ in (2) and the one in $3$ be $a_H$s?

Comment: Yes, thank you.